Compare excel files in python
I want to compare to excel files generated by Pandas.
What I want is that they are exactly the same, not just the content but the formatting as well. If I use filecmp however I get that they are different:
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']],
    index=['row 1', 'row 2'],
    columns=['col 1','col 2']
)
df1.to_excel("output.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet_name_1')
df1.to_excel("output2.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet_name_1')
filecmp.cmp("output.xlsx", "output2.xlsx")

I can, and I did, write a function that loops between all the sheets in the workbooks, all the cells in a sheet, all the attributes in a cell and checks that they are the same. But this is extremely slow. I there any faster way?

Office usually includes the "Spreadsheet Compare" tool, which does what you want in an interactive way. Cannot be automated though. Have a look for it in your Start menu.

Maybe extract the xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml entry of both files and compare them?

@moken An Excel file can store metadata such as the creation time. That's probably why the files are different.

zlib and pycksum have checksum functions that'll do this ... (zlib.crc32 and pycksum.cksum respectfully)

A negative comparison of the sheet1.xml files would not guarantee they are different data wise. If the two Sheets are created the same way as in the example code you'd expect their layout to be the same however if one was created by another means; Excel,  another Python module or other method OR if the workbook modified is modified, the XLM layout of a Sheet may change even if the actual data and formatting in the Sheets is exactly the same.

@moken Sure, but the question says "excel files generated by Pandas" (admittedly 2 distinct versions of Pandas might produce different markup).

@Olivier I did something similar. checking directly the CRC of the xml, i treat the xlsx as a zip file, for now it's good enough, but theres the risk that two files that look the same have different CRC because of some default data that is added when saved by excel

pandas not handle excel file formating (like fonts, colors, borders, etc.) because it focuses on the data itself rather than the file’s visual presentation
This openpyxl python package might help you! openpyxl primarily targets the Excel 2010 format (XLSX). However, it’s still widely used for newer versions of Excel as the XLSX format
import openpyxl

def compare_excel_files(file1, file2):
    # Load the workbooks
    wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook(file1, data_only=True)
    wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook(file2, data_only=True)

    # Compare sheet names
    if wb1.sheetnames != wb2.sheetnames:
        return False

    for sheet_name in wb1.sheetnames:
        ws1 = wb1[sheet_name]
        ws2 = wb2[sheet_name]

        # Compare dimensions (number of rows and columns)
        if ws1.max_row != ws2.max_row or ws1.max_column != ws2.max_column:
            return False

        # Iterate through all cells and compare their values and formatting
        for row in ws1.iter_rows():
            for cell1 in row:
                cell2 = ws2[cell1.coordinate]

                # Compare values
                if cell1.value != cell2.value:
                    return False

                # Compare fonts
                if (cell1.font.name != cell2.font.name or 
                    cell1.font.size != cell2.font.size or 
                    cell1.font.bold != cell2.font.bold or
                    cell1.font.italic != cell2.font.italic or 
                    cell1.font.color != cell2.font.color):
                    return False

                # Compare fills (cell background colors)
                if cell1.fill.fgColor != cell2.fill.fgColor:
                    return False

                # Compare alignments
                if (cell1.alignment.horizontal != cell2.alignment.horizontal or 
                    cell1.alignment.vertical != cell2.alignment.vertical or
                    cell1.alignment.wrap_text != cell2.alignment.wrap_text):
                    return False

                # Compare borders
                if cell1.border != cell2.border:
                    return False

                # Compare number formats
                if cell1.number_format != cell2.number_format:
                    return False

    return True

# Example usage:
file1 = "output.xlsx"
file2 = "output2.xlsx"

if compare_excel_files(file1, file2):
    print("The Excel files are identical in content and formatting.")
else:
    print("The Excel files differ in content or formatting.")


The idea is OK but the border comparison would return False and so the result would always be False for the two workbooks even though the borders are the same

yes this is what I have but if the files are big, it takes a lot of time to check them
